# Codeigniter Pagination issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am trying to get the pagination to work with codeigniter. But am getting the following errors

Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined offset: 0
Filename: controllers/group.php

And

Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: views/group_list_view.php

Following is the code of my Model

```
public function get_list($userid)  
{  
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/portal/index.php/group/index';
    $config['total_rows'] =$this->db->where('UserId',$userid)->get('group')->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    $config['num_links'] = 10;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $query['groups'] = $this->db->get('group', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
    return   $query;

}
```

Here is the code for my controller

```
class Group extends CI_Controller {

 public function __constructor()
 {
    session_start();
    parent::__constructor();
 }


 public function index()
 {
     if(!$this->session->userdata('userid'))
        redirect('login');

     $this->load->model('group_model');
     $result = $this->group_model->get_list($this->session->userdata('$userid'));

     //neither this works
     data['groups'] = $result;
     //nor this
     $data['groups'] = $result[0];

     $this->load->view('group_list_view', $data);
 }
}
```

And this the code in view

```
foreach($groups as $group){
                        echo $group->GroupId;
                    }
```

Can anyone please guide me where am i doing it worng. Apparently no one else seems to have encountered any such problem. I followed the tutorial from [net.tutsplus](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-7-pagination/) ditto but still facing the same issue. Please note i am new to PHP to be gentel :)

Comment: please check correctly pagination code should be controller not on model

Comment: OK. Let me move the code to controller and then try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write the code in controller not in model

```
public function index()
{
    if(!$this->session->userdata('userid'))
        redirect('login');

     $this->load->library('pagination');

     $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/portal/index.php/group/index';
     $config['total_rows'] = // Use the same function to get the number of rows
     $config['per_page'] = 10;
     $config['num_links'] = 10;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $this->load->model('group_model');
    $result = $this->group_model->get_list($this->session->userdata('$userid'));
    data['groups'] = $result;    
    $this->load->view('group_list_view', $data);
}
```

Comment: It's not necessary afaik (though "wrong") to call pagination in a controller. Also, you've a syntax error

Comment: Your answer is wrong actually.Because he even not getting the $result in controller.So what is the need to go for the view.May be its secondary

Comment: I don't understand if you use text speak. Please use all the needed vowels.

Comment: Now it's better :) He's assigning (in one of his try) in the controller, but he's itereting over the wrong value in the view. Where the pagination is loaded it's not the issue here I thinl. Also, you still have a syntax error

Comment: what is that can you please tell me

Comment: Guys, thanks for the help. I have been able to get the data displayed on my view but only fetching the results from DB in Contorller. Now there are 2 questions if any one can help me. 1- Is there a way to fetch results from model and then use in controller? 2- why is that its working when i fetch the records in controller?

Answer (score 0):

Here:

`$query['groups'] = $this->db->get('group', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));`

You're assing the query resultset to `$query['group']`

but in the controller you're doing

```
$data['groups'] = $result;
```

and then you iterate:

```
foreach($groups as $group){
```

**You should be doing instead:**

```
foreach($groups['groups'] as $group){
```

Since your original assignment in the model is to `$query['groups'].`
So, either you assing to `$query` in the model, or you iterate the correct array in the view (like I showed you above)

Comment: Hye, Thanks. It helped me at first but i was still not able to remove the bug. However, when i moved the code to the controller from model my code started working. I am still not able to make it work when data is returned from model :)